# Why crypt_data isn't known?

Tags: c, freebsd, crypt

regarding to the man page of `crypt_r()` of freeBSD all I need to include is

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
```

But it doesn't run. I ofcourse also linked `-lcrypt`

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <crypt.h>
#include "ownstuff"

int CreateUser (some stuff)
{
    //struct crypt_data data; Also didn't work
    crypt_data data;
    char *res;
    data.initialized = 0;

    res = crypt_r("password", "$6$QX", &data);

    return 0;
}
```

So what's wrong?
I don't get it.

**EDIT:**

Also changing the header part to this:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include "ownstuff"
```

Didn't change anything from the error it self.

Comment: `_GNU_SOURCE` on FreeBSD? are you sure? Maybe you got a copy of the glibc man page by mistake...

Comment: Also, you're supposed to define all the `_*_SOURCE` macros you need before including *any* headers. After the `<unistd.h>` include, the feature-selection magic has already happened and it's too late to add `_GNU_SOURCE`.

Comment: @AShelly the error is "error: 'crypt_data' undeclared (first use in this function)
" Or in case of `struct crypt_data data;` the error is, that data's size isn't known.

Comment: @Wumpus Q. Wumbley I don't know this stuff, so probabbly your right, but changing this stuff, still didn't changed anything of the error.

Comment: The point of my first comment is: I don't think `crypt_r` actually exists on BSD.

Comment: probabbly thats it.... i was on the page of CentOS where the header interface is FreeBSD designed.

Comment: There is no crypt_r on FreeBSD-9.2, that's for sure. Nor on 10.x[1].
  [1]: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.0-stable&arch=default&format=html
Seems like a Linux-only call...